# Parsing Entity as Json taking from AzureTable

Tags: java, android, json, azure, gson

I have a Data in Azure Storage (Table), I take that Data and serialize it to Json format throw API, how can I parse it in Java (Android Studio) in Collection of my class?

```
public class Book {
String name;
String author;
String description;

public Book(){}

public Book(String name, String author, String description) {
    this.name = name;
    this.author = author;
    this.description = description;
   }
}
```

JSON which API will give:

```
"{\"operations\":[{\"title\":\"1984\",\"author\":\"Oruel\",\"description\":\"Antiutopy\",\"PartitionKey\":\"Books\",\"RowKey\":\"\",\"Timestamp\":\"2017-03-10T19:23:49.6668457+00:00\",\"ETag\":\"W/\\\"datetime'2017-03-10T19%3A23%3A49.6668457Z'\\\"\"},{\"title\":\"hello\",\"author\":\"world\",\"description\":\"test\",\"PartitionKey\":\"Books\",\"RowKey\":\"32de9806-617a-4b66-9a87-bd3488e9080e\",\"Timestamp\":\"2017-03-08T12:32:45.2881957+00:00\",\"ETag\":\"W/\\\"datetime'2017-03-08T12%3A32%3A45.2881957Z'\\\"\"}]}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to retrieve data from Azure Table Storage and using Java on Android.

The simple way is that using [Azure Storage SDK for Android](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-android) and refer to the offical [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-java-how-to-use-table-storage) to do these operations via rewrite your `Book` class which inherit [`TableServiceEntity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-java-how-to-use-table-storage#how-to-add-an-entity-to-a-table) as below. For more details, please see the [javadocs](http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-android/) of Azure Storage Android SDK.

```
public class Book extends TableServiceEntity {
    String name;
    String author;
    String description;

    public Book(){}

    public Book(String sn, String name, String author, String description) {
        this.partitionKey = "Books";
        this.rowKey = sn;
        this.name = name;
        this.author = author;
        this.description = description;
    }

    // Setter & Getter methods for properties
    ..............
}
```

If you just need to serialize & deserialize the data between `JSON` and POJO Entity, please use [`Gson`](https://github.com/google/gson) library to do it.